# Neo4jClient Connect issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am New to neo4j and neo4jclient and I'm having problems trying to connect to my db. I can verify that the DB is running correctly via the web interface. However in my C# app when I call connect I get an exception throw.

> at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.SendHttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, String commandDescription, HttpStatusCode[]
>   expectedStatusCodes) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line
>   141
>
> at
>   Neo4jClient.GraphClient.SendHttpRequestAndParseResultAs[T](HttpRequestMessage
>   request, String commandDescription, HttpStatusCode[]
>   expectedStatusCodes) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line
>   182
>
> at
>   Neo4jClient.GraphClient.SendHttpRequestAndParseResultAs[T](HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpStatusCode[] expectedStatusCodes) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line
>   177
>
> at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Connect() in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line
>   191
>
> at Neo4J_POC.Pages.AddUser.btn_Add_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in d:\EDGE Next
>   Gen\POC\Neo4J_POC\Neo4J_POC\Pages\AddUser.aspx.cs:line 46

It's being thrown inside the Connect function somewhere.

I'm running on a window 7 , with the .net 4.5 framework & visual Studio 2012 The call to connect looks like:

```
GraphClient _client = new GraphClient(new Uri("Neo4jURL"));

_client.Connect();
```

Which looks correct to me, even I try with my machine IP instead of localhost. But it not working for me .

The exception is coming from our HTTP subsystem, which uses the HttpClient package from Microsoft. This is a .NET 4.5 package which uses async/await constructs. Which is also installed but still I'm facing the issue.

Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http -Version 2.2.22

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: the exception message is missing, and "Neo4jURL" doesn't look like an URL. Perhaps you can share both.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelHunger, are you trying to pull the URL from App.Config? What version of Neo4jClient are you using? Can you try just doing your connection in a simple Console App and see if that works. Also, whack a try/catch around your 'connect' call and see if you get more useful information.

Comment: Hi Chirs/MichaelHunger           , I am using version="1.0.0.656"  for neo4jClient below are the details :   <package id="Neo4jClient" version="1.0.0.656" targetFramework="net45" /> .

Comment: Even i have used try/Catch block around the connect function below are the stacktrace details :at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.SendHttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, String commandDescription, HttpStatusCode[] expectedStatusCodes) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bae2aa9bce99f44\Neo4jClient\GraphClient.cs:line 141
   at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.SendHttpRequestAndParseResultAs[T](HttpRequestMessage request, String commandDescription, HttpStatusCode[] expectedStatusCodes) in

Comment: Have you tried the connection in a simple Console App? Start a brand new console app, and use this as your 'Main' method:

`static void Main() { var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data")); client.Connect(); }`

If you don't get an exception from this, then it's something to do with your other project.

Comment: Yes i try in fresh console Application but still i am getting the same Exception  :(